# While loop with nested for loop

Tags: bash

I need help with bash script.
So I have input data as

```
CellIden="461"
CellIden="465"
CellIden="468"
CellIden="462"
CellIden="466"
CellIden="469"
CellIden="463"
CellIden="467"
CellIden="460"
```

and I have created while loop

```
cat FolderCell2 | while read line ;
do
echo $line | sed -e 's/cellIden/Cell/g'
done > FolderCell3
```

so this will read each line and replace strings, but I need two more loops in this while script :

```
for (( i = 1; i <=$SEC_NUM ; i++ ))
do
for (( j = 1 ; j <=$Cell_Num ; j++ ))
do
sed -e 's/Cell/Cell$i$j/g'
done
done > File
```

the ouput shold be like this

```
Cell11="461"
Cell12="465"
Cell13="468"
Cell21="462"
Cell22="466"
Cell23="469"
Cell31="463"
Cell32="467"
Cell33="460"
```

Variables $SEC_NUM and $Cell_Num are sometimes different. So I don't know how to combine this two codes, `while loop` together with `two for loop` to get ouput as this above.

Comment: input shell var to sed, you need use double quota `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is something that converts 1D array data to 2D array. Only one of (SEC_NUM or Cell_Num) is required in fact.

```
awk -v SEC_NUM=3 '{i=(NR-1)%SEC_NUM+1;j=int((NR-1)/SEC_NUM)+1;sub(/CellIden/,"Cell" j i)}1' file

Cell11="461"
Cell12="465"
Cell13="468"
Cell21="462"
Cell22="466"
Cell23="469"
Cell31="463"
Cell32="467"
Cell33="460"

awk -v SEC_NUM=4 '{i=(NR-1)%SEC_NUM+1;j=int((NR-1)/SEC_NUM)+1;sub(/CellIden/,"Cell" j i)}1' file
Cell11="461"
Cell12="465"
Cell13="468"
Cell14="462"
Cell21="466"
Cell22="469"
Cell23="463"
Cell24="467"
Cell31="460"
```

Answer (score 2):

When parsing line-by-line I find it more convenient to work with an AWK script.

Consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN{
        i=1;
        j=1;
}

{
        split($0,arr,"\"");
        print "Cell" i j "=\"" arr[2] "\""
        j++;
        if (j > CELL_NUM){
                j=1;
                i++;
        }
        if (i > SEC_NUM){
                i=1;
        }
}

END{

}
```

Then assuming the script is test.awk and the input file is 1.txt, run this way:

```
awk -vCELL_NUM=3 -vSEC_NUM=3 -f test.awk 1.txt
```

Getting your wanted output:

```
Cell11="461"
Cell12="465"
Cell13="468"
Cell21="462"
Cell22="466"
Cell23="469"
Cell31="463"
Cell32="467"
Cell33="460"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
i=1
while read -r line;
do
    j=1
    sed "s/CellIden=/Cell$i$j=/" <<< "$line"
    for ((j=2; j<=$Cell_Num; j++)); do
        read -r line
        sed "s/CellIden=/Cell$i$j=/" <<< "$line"
    done
    ((i++))
done < FolderCell2 > file.out
```

Comment: not really, take a look on numbering in ouput file. Variables "i" and "j" are different, andwith your code are the same whole time. Check my ouput data..Cell11, Cell12, Cell13, Cell21 ...etc

Comment: @anishsane: Many many thanks for editing my answer to suite OP's needs. Much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

```
SEC_NUM=3
CellNum=3

i=0
j=0

while read line ; do
  echo  "${line/CellIden/Cell$((i+1))$((j+1))}"
  ((j=(j+1)%CellNum))
  [ $j -eq 0 ] && ((i=(i+1)%SEC_NUM))
done < "$infile" > "$outfile"
```

The variable j will be incremented in every loop cycle.
The variable i will be incremented in every SEC_NUM-th cycle.
The replacement is done with a parameter substitution to avoid 
sed.

For

```
SEC_NUM=3
CellNum=4
```

the output is

```
Cell11="461"
Cell12="465"
Cell13="468"
Cell14="462"
Cell21="466"
Cell22="469"
Cell23="463"
Cell24="467"
Cell31="460"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
i=0
while read -r line;
do
    j=$(bc <<< "obase=$Cell_Num; $i" | xargs printf "%02d" | tr '[0-8]' '[1-9]')
    sed "s/CellIden=/Cell$j=/" <<< "$line"
    ((i++))
done < FolderCell2 > file.out
```

Effectively, encode the number with base 3 ($Cell_Num),
then print with leading zeros.
Finally, since your numbering starts with 1, not 0, replace all 0-8 with 1-9.